# Calorie Tracker

Tags: java, beginner

I used the little I picked up from my few days learning code to complete this simple code that takes a users Name, Age, Calorie goal and current Calorie intake.
This is by no means impressive, I've only been coding for 3 days but I'd like to know of ways to write this program in a more OPTIMAL manner, hopefully this is allowed.

I will post the code from both the Main class and Info class. I'm looking for any tips that could make projects like this more optimal in the future, as I assume 160+ lines we not needed for this simple program. I did include failsafes for situations like Non-integer inputs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
 // THIS IS PART OF Main.java
public class ClassOne {




public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Please tell me your name.");
    Scanner NI = new Scanner(System.in);
    String NameInput = NI.nextLine();
    Info user = new Info();
    user.name = NameInput;


    // Name is printed below
    System.out.println("Hello there " + NameInput + "!");
    String AgeVerification = "no";
    do {
        System.out.println("How old are you?");
        Scanner UA = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Starts asking for age
        while (!UA.hasNextInt()) {  

              System.out.println("This is not a number. Please type your age - Ex: 12, 28, 52, etc");
         String INVALIDUA = UA.next();
        }
        // If Age is a number - Continue
        int UserAge = UA.nextInt();

    System.out.println("So," + NameInput + " you are " + UserAge + ". Is that correct?");
    System.out.println("Type Yes or No.");
    // Confirms age
    Scanner AV = new Scanner(System.in);
    AgeVerification = AV.nextLine();
    if ( AgeVerification.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") ) {
        System.out.println("Thank you for confirming your age!");
        // If user says yes. Continue.
    }
    else if (AgeVerification.isEmpty() || AgeVerification == null) {
        System.out.println("You did not answer the question.. Let's try again.");
        //If User does comment. Re-enter age
        continue;
    }
    else if (AgeVerification.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
     System.out.println("My bad! What is your age then?");
    else {
        System.out.println("That wasn't an option..was it? Let's try again!");
        // If user doesn't enter yes or no. Take as no and retry.
        continue;
    }
    user.age = UserAge;


    }while( !AgeVerification.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || AgeVerification == null);

    // Defining CGCHECK1 as global Variable 
    String CGCheck1 = "no";
    do {
    System.out.println("How many calories do you aim to intake?");
    Scanner CG = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(!CG.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please Enter the goal in numbers only. EX: '4000'");
        String InvalidCG = CG.next();
        //Checks Calorie Goal Input. If not an interger, Retry!
    }
    int CalG = CG.nextInt();
    user.goal = CalG;
    System.out.println("Your Goal is " + CalG + " . Is that Correct? Yes or No?");
    Scanner CgCheck = new Scanner(System.in);
    CGCheck1 = CgCheck.nextLine();
    if (CGCheck1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Great! You may now begin your daily log!");
    }

    else if (CGCheck1.isEmpty() || CGCheck1 == null) {
        System.out.println("You did not answer the question.. Let's try again.");
        //If User does comment. Re-enter age
        continue;
    }
    else if (CGCheck1.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
        System.out.println("Okay, My bad!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("That wasn't an option..was it? Let's try again!");
        // If user doesn't enter yes or no. Take as no and retry.
        continue;



    }
    int CaloGoal = CalG;
    }while (!CGCheck1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")); 

// Goal - FirstIntake = RemainingGoal then Remaining goal - NextIntake = Remaining Goal 
    int Run = 1;
    user.CR = 0;
    int start = 1;
    do {

        System.out.println("Enter each calorie intake. This will subtract from your daily goal.");
    System.out.println("Ex: 250, then later 300, then later 500. This will take 1000 from your current goal.");
    Scanner II = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(!II.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please Enter the Intake in numbers only. EX: '350'");
        String InvalidII = II.next();
        // Checks if Initial Intake is a Interger. 
}
    int InitialIntake = II.nextInt();
    user.current = user.current + InitialIntake;
    int CR = InitialIntake - user.goal;

    if (start == 1) {
        // Checks if Intake is less than goal or If user has reached goal.
    user.CR =user.goal - InitialIntake;

    System.out.println("You have taken in  " + InitialIntake + " calories!");
    System.out.println(" You have " + user.CR + " calories left!");
     System.out.println("You have taken in " + user.current + " calories!");
    start++;
        // After this code runs. The if statement is nolonger true, It will now move to else if. 
    }
    else if (user.CR > 0) {
        user.CR = user.CR - InitialIntake;
        System.out.println("You have taken in  " + InitialIntake + " calories!");
        System.out.println(" You have " + user.CR + " calories left!");
         System.out.println("You have taken in " + user.current + " calories!");
        }

    else if (user.CR <= 0) {
     System.out.println("You have reached your goal! Congratulations!");
     System.out.println("You have taken in " + user.current + " calories!");
    }
    } while ( Run == 1);



}

 }
```

Below is Info.java

```
       //this is Info.java
public class Info{
    int age;
    String name;
    int goal;
    int current;
    int CR;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

congrats on your first days of coding. The problem of every person starting to code is writing too many things in main - like its one large bowl of everything. Or spaghetti ;)

So step 1 - if the class is public it should have ENCAPSULATION - private fields and getters/setters.

```
public class Info{
   int age;
   String name;
   int goal;
   int current;
   int CR;
}
```

Becomes:

```
public class Info {
        private int age;
        private String name;
        private int goal;
        private int current;
        private int CR;

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getGoal() {
            return goal;
        }

        public void setGoal(int goal) {
            this.goal = goal;
        }

        public int getCurrent() {
            return current;
        }

        public void setCurrent(int current) {
            this.current = current;
        }

        public int getCR() {
            return CR;
        }

        public void setCR(int CR) {
            this.CR = CR;
        }
    }
```

Next one is naming. In Java we have came case naming, so variables are not

```
String NI
```

But 
    String ni;

But that's another problem. Variable names should be clear and meaningful. 
a1, b2, smgxxx means not much. Better to spend time and name it properly

To avoid "Magic strings" means having random strings here and there, it makes sense to define private static final constants named uppercase. So the code will start to look like this.

```
        private static final String ASK_USERS_NAME = "Please tell me your name.";
        private static final String WELCOME_USER_TEMPLATE = "Hello there %s!%n";
        private static final String ASK_USERS_AGE = "How old are you?";
        private static final String CALORIES_AIM_INTAKE = "How many calories do you aim to intake?";
        private static final String GOAL_IN_NUMBERS_PROMPT = "Please Enter the goal in numbers only. EX: '4000'";
        private static final String YES = "yes";
        private static final String NO = "no";
        private static final String VALID_AGE_PROMPT = "This is not a number. Please type your age - Ex: 12, 28, 52, etc";
        private static final String DAILY_LOG_BEGIN_CONGRATS = "Great! You may now begin your daily log!";
        private static final String YES_NO_PROMPT = "Type Yes or No.";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(ASK_USERS_NAME);
            Scanner NI = new Scanner(System.in);
            String NameInput = NI.nextLine();
            Info user = new Info();
            user.name = NameInput;

            // Name is printed below
            System.out.printf(WELCOME_USER_TEMPLATE, NameInput);
            String AgeVerification = NO;
            do {
                System.out.println(ASK_USERS_AGE);
                Scanner UA = new Scanner(System.in);
                // Starts asking for age
                while (!UA.hasNextInt()) {

                    System.out.println(VALID_AGE_PROMPT);
                    String INVALIDUA = UA.next();
                }
                // If Age is a number - Continue
                int UserAge = UA.nextInt();

                System.out.println("So," + NameInput + " you are " + UserAge + ". Is that correct?");
                System.out.println(YES_NO_PROMPT);
```

I hope that's enough for the starter. My advice - get into object-oriented design, see what is SOLID. It will help your coding journey. Tnx!

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. I will be sure to review this and follow these tips. Thank you.